# Why does my rock paper scissors program not work?

Tags: python

I am a beginner programmer and I just don't understand why my rock paper scissors program doesn't work, it worked previously but I tried adding a step to repeat if the user presses r. Where did I screw up?

This first program is before I tried to add the restart. It works as I expect.

```
from random import randint
options = {1:"Rock",2:"Paper",3:"Scissors"}##This list is for the raw data to output

number = randint(1,3)###Random selection of rock paper or scissors
computer = options[number]

print "Rock, Paper, Scissors Key"
print "1 = Rock"
print "2 = Paper"
print "3 = Scissors"

human = input("Enter what you want. ")
print "Player chose",options[human]


def end(computer,human):
    if computer == human:
        return "Draw"
    elif computer == 1 and human == 2:
        return "Computer chose Rock, Player has won!"
    elif computer == 1 and human == 3:
        return "Computer chose Rock, Player has lost."
    elif computer == 2 and human == 1:
        return "Computer chose Paper, Player has won!"
    elif computer == 2 and human == 3:
        return "Computer chose Paper, Player has lost"
    elif computer == 3 and human == 1:
        return "Computer chose Scissors, Player has won!"
    elif computer == 3 and human == 2:
        return "Computer chose Scissors, Player has lost."
    else:
        return "ERROR"
print end(number, human)

input("To finish press any key.")
```

This next program is when I tried to add a restart function. This one doesn't work any longer. Why?

```
from random import randint
i = 1
while i == 1:

    options = {1:"Rock",2:"Paper",3:"Scissors"}

    number = randint(1,3)###Random selection of rock paper or scissors
computer = options[number]

print "Rock, Paper, Scissors Key"
print "1 = Rock"
print "2 = Paper"
print "3 = Scissors"

human = input("Enter what you want. ")
print "Player chose",options[human]


def end(computer,human):
        if computer == human:
            return "Draw"
        elif computer == 1 and human == 2:
            return "Computer chose Rock, Player has won!"
        elif computer == 1 and human == 3:
            return "Computer chose Rock, Player has lost."
        elif computer == 2 and human == 1:
            return "Computer chose Paper, Player has won!"
        elif computer == 2 and human == 3:
            return "Computer chose Paper, Player has lost"
        elif computer == 3 and human == 1:
            return "Computer chose Scissors, Player has won!"
        elif computer == 3 and human == 2:
            return "Computer chose Scissors, Player has lost."
        else:
            return "ERROR"
print end(number, human)
restart_var = input("Press R to restart and Enter to exit")
def restart(x):
        if x == r:
            i = 1
        else:
            i = 0
restart(restart_var)
```

Comment: Do you have error message? Or wrong behavior of your program? Add this information in the question!

Comment: Second version of the program has an infinite loop and will just hang until you kill it. Both versions compare the `computer` and `human` values to numbers (`== 1`, etc) even though they are strings (`options[1]`, for example, is `"Rock"`, not 1).

Comment: There is more than 1 mistake in your code

Comment: A better design would be to default to running a new game immediately, and offer quit as one of the options on the game menu -- in fact, maybe quit on any input which is not 1-3.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: Is the indentation in this question actually what you have in code? Because the indentation could well be part of the problem. Python uses whitespace to identify scope.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is here:

```
if x == r:
```

You compare `x` with unknown variable `r`.

Right way to do it is to compare with string 'r' because `input` returns string.

```
if x == 'r':
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have in the first script has an error when finding the option the user chose from the input. `input` will give you a string back, and not actually a number. You can convert it to a number by using `int(input("Enter what you want"))`

This will work fine. The next thing to do is allow restarting. All you have to do is make a function that starts the program. like this:

```
def start():

    print("Rock, Paper, Scissors Key")
    print("1 = Rock")
    print("2 = Paper")
    print("3 = Scissors")

    number = randint(1,3)
    computer = options[number]

    human = int(input("Enter what you want. "))
    print("Player chose",options[human])
```

Now call your `end` function within the `start` function:

```
    print(end(number, human))
```

And now you just have to check that last input to see if the user wants to restart.

```
    if input("Press R to restart and Enter to exit").lower() == "r":
        start()
```

So your new final script looks like this:

```
from random import randint
options = {1:"Rock",2:"Paper",3:"Scissors"}##This list is for the raw data to output

def end(computer,human):
    if computer == human:
        return "Draw"
    elif computer == 1 and human == 2:
        return "Computer chose Rock, Player has won!"
    elif computer == 1 and human == 3:
        return "Computer chose Rock, Player has lost."
    elif computer == 2 and human == 1:
        return "Computer chose Paper, Player has won!"
    elif computer == 2 and human == 3:
        return "Computer chose Paper, Player has lost"
    elif computer == 3 and human == 1:
        return "Computer chose Scissors, Player has won!"
    elif computer == 3 and human == 2:
        return "Computer chose Scissors, Player has lost."
    else:
        return "ERROR"


def start():

    #display the game info
    print("Rock, Paper, Scissors Key")
    print("1 = Rock")
    print("2 = Paper")
    print("3 = Scissors")

    #get a random number for the computer
    number = randint(1,3)
    computer = options[number]

    #get human input
    human = int(input("Enter what you want. "))

    #print what the human chose
    print("Player chose",options[human])

    #run the calculator
    print(end(number, human))

    if input("Press R to restart and Enter to exit ").lower() == "r":
        print('\n'*3) #print some line breaks
        start()

#start the game
start()
```

**Note** I wrote this in Python 3. If you are using Python 2 instead, change `input` to `raw_input`.

Comment: @YogeeshSeralathan I rolled back your Python2.x edit as it seems apparent that the OP is using Py3.

Comment: It sure wasn't apparent to me; OP's (asker, I mean) code is full of print statements.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the second example has only two assignments indented after the `while`. That would cause an infinite loop, as the thing breaking its condition is at the end of the program.

Secondly, in Python 2, `input()` parses expressions (which incidentally makes it very dangerous), which is why it was replaced in Python 3. This works as you want for numbers, but not letters, which it would look up as variables. You can abuse this to make your code sort of work:

```
r="Willy Wonka's shoes didn't taste so well."
R=r
val=input("Can you type R? ")
if val in (r, R):
  print "You could! Or maybe you typed my secret phrase in quotes. I don't know!"
```

Notably, this means if the user just hits Enter they get a SyntaxError exception - because an empty string isn't a valid Python expression. Same for typing a keyword, and undefined variables will get them NameError.

The function to use instead is called `raw_input`, and always produces a string (in Python 3, that is what input does). You could wrap it in a bit of code to make it a little more helpful:

```
def read_int(question=""):
  val=None
  while val is None:
    s=raw_input(question)
    try:
      val=int(s,0)
    except ValueError, e:
      pass
  return val
def confirm_letter(question="", letter="y"):
  s=raw_input(question)
  return s.lower().startswith(letter)
```

Speaking of functions, I think you could use more of them. Control flow like your restart gets much easier to read (and edit!) if, rather than having the whole program in between, it looks like:

```
while True:
  play_game()
  if not confirm_letter("Type R to restart: ", "r"):
    break
```

As a further exercise, I would be tempted to write a class for the player actions, which would know how to compare (to see who won) and represent their names.

Answer (score 0):

`human=input("Enter what you want:")` is a string type. Try `print options[int(human)]` or make human as int like `human=int(input("Enter what you want:"))`

And in the `end` function, it seems like you are comparing `strings` to `integers`. A better implementation would be helpful. You can try comparing the strings instead. `computer="Rock" and options[human]="Scissors" return "Computer chose Rock, Player has lost"`

Comment: Not actually true. As you can tell by the print statements, it's Python 2, which means input() returns anything it pleases, because it parses expressions. That means most non-number things a user could type result in errors immediately. And asker already stated the first program worked as expected, to allow us to focus on the changes.

Comment: @yann thanks I use python 3 and it gave me String type. Thanks again for the clarification.